# Compiling ffmpeg for windows with WebM libraries using Cygwin

Tags: ffmpeg, cygwin

I'm trying to compile FFmpeg with the following configure command, however I'm getting an error saying that it cannot locate one of the libraries I'm trying to enable.

```
./configure \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-ffplay \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-version3 \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
--arch=x86 \
--cpu=core2 \
--prefix=$HOME/host/builds/ffmpeg \
--target-os=mingw32 \
--cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- \
--enable-w32threads \
--enable-postproc \
--enable-libvpx \
--enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libxvid \
--enable-encoder=mjpeg \
--enable-decoder=mjpeg \
--enable-encoder=wmv2 \
--enable-decoder=wmv2 \
--disable-encoder=libx264
```

I'm getting the following error saying that it cannot locate libvpx or it is the wrong version:

```
ERROR: libvpx decoder version must be >=0.9.1
```

**However, my cygwin package installer says that libvpx, libvpx1 and libvpx-devl is currently on version 1.0.3-1**. I've listed the packages with `cygcheck -c` and it says that the packages are all installed OK.

Any ideas what could be causing this or how to resolve it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899290/error-libvpx-decoder-version-must-be-0-9-1) might be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I've actually had a read through that already which led me to check that the package is actually installed properly. Going through that process is what has bought me to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libvpx-devel` package is for native building, but based on those configure flags, you are trying to cross-compile ffmpeg for mingw64.  Therefore, you need mingw64-compiled versions of any libraries you enable in order to use them with this build.